# How to set default class on component if user not set class?

Tags: vuejs2

A custom component need to set a default className if the caller not define it. How to do this?

The component :

`Vue.component('the-component', {
  template: 'div class="default-class">...</div>',
  ...
});`

`<the-component></the-component>` render to `div class="default-class"></div>` is what I want.

but `<the-component :class='user-class'></the-component>`
actual render to `div class="user-class default-class"></div>`
but I wanna `div class="user-class"></div>`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer but this could be achieved by doing something like:

```
computed: {
  compClass () {
    return 'class' in this.$vnode.data ? '' : 'default-class'
  },
}
```

You can check to see if a class was passed, if it was then have this return nothing as the class has already been added, otherwise add your default class.